# Find the derivative of $g(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} x+e^{1-x} & x < 1 \\ 2 & x=1\\ \ln(x) &x > 1\end{array}\right.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $g$ be the function defined by
>
> $g(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} x+e^{1-x} & x < 1 \\ 2 & x=1\\
>  \ln(x) &x > 1\end{array}\right.$
>
> Which of the following is the derivative of $g$, or $g'(x)$?
>
> a) $g(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 1-e^{1-x} & x < 1 \\ 0 & x=1\\
>  \frac{1}{x} &x > 1\end{array}\right.$
>
> b) $g(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 1-e^{1-x} & x < 1 \\ \\
>  \frac{1}{x} &x > 1\end{array}\right.$

My book says the right answer is b), but I don't understand why. I know how to calculate the derivatives for each piece of this function, no issue there, my question is:

- Why isn't option a) the right one, if $(2)' = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps it is due to the fact that the right sided limit does not exist for the derivative at 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the function $g$ is not continuous at $x = 1$, because $\ln (1) = 0 \neq 2$. This implies that $g$ is not derivable at $x=1$, so that's why $g'$ can't be defined there. Here you have the graph of $g$.

[image: g]